# Partial differential equation in Lagrange form.

Tags: linear-pde

Solve the pde.

$$(my(x+y)-nz^2)p-(lx(x+y)-nz^2)q=(lx-my)z$$

Using method of multipliers$(1,1,(x+y)/z)$ I got one of the solutions 
$$(x+y)z=c_1$$

I can't figure out what the other solution might be.

PS: $p$ and $q$ are pde wrt to x and y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(my(x+y)-nz^2)p-(lx(x+y)-nz^2)q=(lx-my)z$$
$$\frac{dx}{my(x+y)-nz^2}=\frac{dy}{-lx(x+y)+nz^2}=\frac{dz}{(lx-my)z}=$$
$$=\frac{dx+dy+\frac{x+y}{z}}{my(x+y)-nz^2-lx(x+y)+nz^2+\frac{x+y}{z}(lx-my)z}=\frac{dx+dy+\frac{x+y}{z}dz}{0}$$
$$\frac{dx+dy}{x+y}+\frac{dz}{z}=0$$
$$\ln|x+y|+\ln|z|=\text{constant}$$
$$(x+y)z=c_1$$
I agree with your first characteristic equation.

Second characteristic equation, with multipliers $(lx,my,0)$ :
$$\frac{lxdx+mydy}{lxmy(x+y)-lxnz^2-mylx(x+y)+mynz^2}=\frac{lxdx+mydy}{-(lx-my)z^2}
=\frac{dz}{(lx-my)z}$$
$$lxdx+mydy+zdz=0$$
$$lx^2+my^2+z^2=c_2$$